# Avoid the blue color of the selected field in BlackBerry WebWorks

Tags: html, css, blackberry, input, focus

I have html content which a native application built with PhoneGap.
This application has 2 fields, one of text and a texarea.
When I write in each activates the blue background, and I can see thoroughly.

How I can disable that blue?

Comment: outline:0 for focus & default state will solve your problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

If it's using CSS then the code activating the blue background will probably look something like this:

```
textfield:focus, textarea:focus {
   background-color:blue;
}
```

If that is the case then you can simply remove that CSS rule and it should solve your problem.

Alternatively, the background colour may be being added through javascript in which case you'd have to check your javascript files to see where it is happening and remove it from there.